# How to make NSWindow look disabled and not respond to user input?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm not sure that there's some system-level feature like that. Anyway, is there a way to make NSWindow looks disabled and does not respond to user input?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think mdominick's answer is correct. Since I only wanted to disable the NSTextFields and NSButtons, I came up with this:

```
for (NSView *item in [self.window.contentView subviews])
{
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]] || [item isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]])
    {
        [(id)item setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

EDIT

Whilst working on a new app, this method in a subclass of NSWindow was really convenient

```
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    [self setEnabled:enabled view:self.window.contentView];
}

- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled view:(id)view
{
    if ([view isHidden]) return;

    for (NSView *item in [view subviews])
    {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSProgressIndicator class]])
        {
            NSProgressIndicator *pI = (NSProgressIndicator *)item;
            [pI setHidden:enabled];
            if (!enabled) [pI startAnimation:nil];
            if (enabled) [pI stopAnimation:nil];
        }
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]] || [item isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]] || [item isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]])
        {
            [(id)item setEnabled:enabled];
            continue;
        }
        if (item.subviews.count)
        {
            [self setEnabled:enabled view:item];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
[someWindow setAlpha:0.5]; // you can change this number to you visual taste.
[someWindow setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES];
```

Comment: maybe this was different in 2012, but in 2014, calling -setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES causes clicks to go through the window. They are not just ignored, but the click will be forwarded to the window that is behind it in the desktop (OS X 10.10)

Comment: Agreed. That worked in previous versions of OS X but doesn't now. Also, I'd actually suggest @mmackh's answer below as a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Since the first answer would still allow keyboard inputs,** I would make it **clean** and **walk trough each UI element in a loop and set it to disabled** in addition to make the window half visible. (Edit: mmackh's answer has the code to do this.)

Or you you use the easy way and simply add an invisible `NSView` on top of your window that is firstResponder and "catches" all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As a different option, one can have a hidden window with NSMakeRect(0,0,10,0) height 0 and write a disableWindow method in the windowController or window subclass that throws a panel with the above hidden window. On opening the panel the screen will be disabled.
enableWindow would alternatively orderOut the above stated hiddenWindow re-enabling the main window.